# Fade in Image on load using transition

Tags: css, transition, fadein

Im a designer so excuse me if my question is simple
I need the background image to fade in when the page loads.

this code was done by a template, so i need to change this background to fade in, because the entire page is already fade in with a plugin on wordpress.

I have this code:

```
body {
background-position: 100% 60px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
transition: background-position 700ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

@media(min-width: 1025px) {
body {
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/girl-banner-desktop.png);
    background-size: 552px 616px;
}
body.load-done:not(.menu-open) {
    background-position: 100% 60px;
}
}

@media(max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {
body.load-done {
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/girl-banner-tablet.png);
    background-size: 351px 327px;
}
body.load-done:not(.menu-open) {
    background-position: 100% 60px;
}
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
body.load-done {
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/girl-banner-mobile.png);
    background-size: 264px 268px;
    background-position: 100% 340px;
}
selector {
    height: 397px;
}
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217313/only-background-image-has-to-fade-in-on-page-load Check this link already answered.

Comment: i saw already this solutions i just dont know how to implement. how the code will be.

Comment: you are not using keyframe which you create how you image with fade in either you don't apply any fade effect on it

Comment: so you can understand this is the website: http://2018.mastertransfer.co.uk/

Comment: i need the corner image background with the girl to fade in as the whole website is already fading in.